# Чтение бинарного файла с нужной позиции (C#)

Tags: c#, файлы

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как в **C#** прочитать данные с нужной позиции? Есть код, написанный на **С++ Builder** с использованием **WinAPI**:

```
S = "D:/DELETE/s281216_1.dat";
fser = CreateFile(
    AnsiString(S).c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

if (fser != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    long int ss = sizeof(str_sm) + ((nrs.n.nr - 1) * (sizeof(ser)));
    SetFilePointer(fser, ss, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(fser, &sr, sizeof(ser), &lread, NULL);
    CloseHandle(fser);
    flag = true;
}
```

Как прочитать данные так же (со смещением) в **С#**? Вот что есть у меня на **C#**:

```
using (BinaryReader readerSr = new BinaryReader(File.Open(S, FileMode.Open)))
{
    while (readerSr.PeekChar() > -1) // | reader2.PeekChar() > -1)
    {
        uint n = readerSr.ReadUInt16();
    }
}
```

Comment: Может это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678883/c-sharp-read-specific-bytes-of-an-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть метод [`FileStream.Seek(Int64, SeekOrigin)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx), можете его вызвать напрямую, или через [`BinaryReader.BaseStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader.basestream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает, а не поможете как посчитать размер структур ? через Length ? Спасибо\